# Javascript chat showing same messages multiple times

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, chat

i am trying to get a chat working that is a copy paste from a tutorial. For some reason the chat load funcion seems to run twice everytime its supposed to run once! This is killing me, i cant figure out whats wrong.

Here is my copy paste chat: http://www.releazed.com/chat/

here is the full source code: http://myslimchatroom.wikidot.com/

I would think its something related to the last_message_id but ive been debuging it and it seems to know the right one...

Please help :(

Comment: That is a lot of code to wade through. Can you identify the relevant snippet of code and post it here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with `console.log`?

Comment: Anyway, by the looks it seems the `Load` method, called immediatelly after `Send` method, must be loading the new messages disregarding the client account.

Comment: removed it and nothing changed, updated the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the problem by simply removing one of the most important parts of the JS `eval(result);` lol... i guess jquery does this on its own? Well its working...

Answer (score 0):

replace  **Load** )

from the end of send with a function that just writes to the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your php code from

```
 $js .= "last_message_id = $last_message_id;";
```

to

```
 $js .= "last_message_id = $last_message_id + 1;";
```

Comment: dont think thats needed as a new last_message_id is set before that.

Comment: Did you try it? I think it happens because you print the message in the SEND command, and you also have the timer that display the same message because you need to increase the messages counter after the user post a new message

Answer (score 0):

This might work, in the Load() function change the $post command to this:

```
              $.post("ajax.php",
        {
              act: "load", // point out that it is downloading messages
              last: last_message_id, // pass number of the last message that the user was last boot
              rand: (new Date()).getTime()
        },
           function (result) { // this function as a parameter is passed javascript code, which we must comply
                eval(result); // execute script from the server
                $(".chat").scrollTop($(".chat").get(0).scrollHeight); // scrolls the message down
                load_in_process = false; // say that downloading is over, we can now start a new download
        }, 
       "text");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the if statement to see if the load is already in process is somehow missing from the Load() function. (It was fine in the place you copied from, I don't know what went wrong):

```
function Load() {
    // Check whether we can download the message. This is done to ensure that we do not start the download again, if the old download is not over yet.
    if(!load_in_process) //this line was missing
    { //also missing
            load_in_process = true; // Loading started
            // refer the request to the server, which returns us javascript
            $.post("ajax.php",
            {
                  act: "load", // point out that it is downloading messages
                  last: last_message_id, // pass number of the last message that the user was last boot
                  rand: (new Date()).getTime()
            },
               function (result) { // this function as a parameter is passed javascript code, which we must comply
                    eval(result); // execute script from the server
                    $(".chat").scrollTop($(".chat").get(0).scrollHeight); // scrolls the message down
                    load_in_process = false; // say that downloading is over, we can now start a new download
            });
   } //also missing
}
```